# Question about topology

Tags: general-topology

How  to  attempt  the  following  question?

> **Question**: Let $Y=[0,1]$, considered as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology $\tau=\{ I \subseteq \mathbb{R} \mid I\text{ an open interval}\}.$ Find the subspace topology.

Here are my steps:

1. Let   $I = (a,b)$.
   Let   $\underline{T}={Y\cap U\mid  U\tau T}$.

   - $(a ,b) \cap Y= (a, b)$  if  $a, b \in Y$.
   - $(a, b)\cap Y=(0, b]$  if  only  $b \in  Y$.
   - $(a ,b)\cap Y= (a,1]$  if only  $a \in Y$.
   - $(a, b)\cap Y= Y$ or  $\emptyset$  if neither  $a$ nor $b$ are in $Y$.
     Then,  $\underline{T}= \{ \emptyset, [0,b), (a,1], Y\}$.

I am not sure whether I can include $(a, b)$ in $\underline{T}$!

$\underline{T}=\{  \emptyset, [0,b), (a,1], Y\}$

Comment: Once you receive a satisfactory answer to your question, you should "accept" it by clicking on the check mark on the left side of an answer, near the vote up/vote down buttons.

Comment: You can! Your reasoning is entirely right. You even have written on one line, $(a,b) \cap Y = (a,b)$ if $(a,b) \in Y$. Without this you have not specified the topology completely. (I do think you have specified a correct _subbasis_ for the topology)

Comment: Typing "\subset" and "\subseteq" in math mode will give you $\subset$ and $\subseteq$, respectively.

Comment: Please take some time to format your posts. There is no need to put three or four spaces between every word, and you should spend a bit of time learning some of the basic mark-up. This post was a mess.

Comment: $\tau$ is not a topology.

Comment: @ Arturo; ok, so now what can i do?

Comment: @leopard: First, state the problem **correctly.** Then, do some thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\tau$ is not a topology on $\mathbb{R}$: it is not closed under arbitrary unions (the union of two disjoint open intervals is not an open interval). So the entire problem starts on the wrong foot.

**Added.** It's possible that $\tau$ is meant to be the topology **generated** by the open intervals.

Your description of $(a,b)\cap Y$ when $a\notin Y$ and $b\in Y$ is incorrect. Presumably, you meant $(a,b)\cap Y = [0,b)$, not $(0,b]$.

Your description of $\underline{T}$ is incorrect; first, you shouldn't just be considering a single interval $(a,b)$; you should be considering **all** intervals. Certainly $\underline{T}$ contains more than just four things in it.

What makes you doubt whether you have subsets of the form $(a,b)$ in $\tau\cap Y$? If $0\leq a\lt b\leq 1$, then $(a,b)\cap Y = (a,b)$, so $(a,b)\in\tau\cap Y$.

**Added.** So if you want to consider the topology generated by the open intervals, first you should give an appropriate/correct description of the intersection with $Y$, and then check to see that if you let $\tau$ be the topology generated by the open intervals on $\mathbb{R}$, then the induced topology on $Y$ is equal to the topology generated by the intersections of open intervals with $Y$.

Comment: @leopard: You also need to find where the shift key in your keyboard is hiding...